# Elegant way to construct a UIView with params from Xib

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a `UIView` subclass that i want to instantiate from my code during runtime which should present a custom picker such that its range (min, max) will be loaded from a server.
I'm looking for a nice way to call a single method that will:

```
* get the view from the Xib
* set its min, max properties so its can draw itself
```

I can create `init(withMin:Int, max:Int)`
But the view won't load from nib so `awakeFromNib` never gets called (which have some initialize code there)

Thanks for the helpers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to just create a `static function` inside the subclass

```
class SomeView: UIView {
    var someInt: Int = 0
    var someString: String = ""

    static func instantiate(owner: AnyObject?, someInt: Int, someString: String) -> SomeView
        // create the View
        let newView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SomeView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! SomeView

        // set properties
        newView.someString = someString
        newView.someInt = someInt

        return newView
    }

    ...
    some other codes here
    ...
}
```

The use of this would be like this.

```
let someView = SomeView.instantiate(owner: self, someInt: 100, someString: "LOOL")
self.view.addSubView(someView)
```